# What is it called when you use the word 'you' like in this sentence to refer to any person and not just you specifically?

Tags: terminology, figures-of-speech

While having a conversation, I say: "When you say atheist, most people would imagine an anti-religious person". What I meant by 'you' is actually anybody. When I am using 'you' in such a manner, what am I doing? Is there a name/word for it? Is it using a 'figure of speech'?

Thank you

Comment: Related: [One - does common English usage equate that to “you” (2nd person) or “he/she” (3rd person)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46468/one-does-common-english-usage-equate-that-to-you-2nd-person-or-he-she-3) I doubt there would be a specific grammatical term for such "obfuscation" of the subject *(**you = I, we, they, anyone, someone,** etc.).* Sometimes it might be seen as a kind of "hedging" - *When one isn't willing to explicitly identify **oneself** in a given context, one can often sidestep the issue by using a different [pro]noun that actually means much the same.*

Comment: The link I posted above is an open question, so new (and more detailed) answers can be posted.

Comment: The following question was closed for being "unclear" [Is there a grammatical name for the third-person 'you'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/341988/is-there-a-grammatical-name-for-the-third-person-you) but the answers there had more upvotes.  Yet another question, closed, with identical answers here:  [What is it called or the term for when I use the word “You” to mean “Everyone”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/350854/what-is-it-called-or-the-term-for-when-i-use-the-word-you-to-mean-everyone)

Answer (score 2):

This informal usage of the second person pronoun not directed to a specific person or group is called the *ubiquitous you*. It substitutes for the indefinite *one*, which seems too formal to some, although *someone* or *somebody* does equally well in most registers.

**Addendum**

The term is found in these [grammar exercises in Sweden](http://www3.kau.se/kurstorg/files/e/82F319241889d1B650Npsr6D0D8A/Exercise%20the%20ubiquitous%20you.pdf),  a [discussion of a Maya Angelou poem](https://www.enotes.com/homework-help/what-authors-intention-maya-angelous-still-rise-657564), a [blog for teachers of composition](http://compositionclassroom.blogspot.de/2015/04/point-of-view-in-academic-writing.html), a [handout for high school students](https://web.jerichoschools.org/hs/teachers/lfischer/grammar/pronouns2.pdf), an [explanatory parenthetical](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/wow/topic/20760997445?page=6) in a forum post, and finally, [not quite understood](http://www.pleasechaseme.com/about/) in a blog post. Considering how long ago I learned the term, if it hadn’t been in use since that time, I doubt seriously if it would show up at all. Perhaps others learned and use a different terminology, but the main point is that this usage is not as a second personal pronoun addressing a specific person or group, but as an indefinite third person. Whatever terminology conveys that meaning is sufficient.

Comment: I think that this is a better answer than the one obtained by the duplicate.

Comment: @Nigel J Incorrect. The article there doesn't use 'ubiquitous you' the way 'generic / impersonal / indefinite you' are used. The latter are fixed phrases / compounds. The usage in the linked article is equivalent to 'the wide-ranging word _you_'; try searching elsewhere for the string. The article even makes this clear, italicising 'you' but not the freely-associated adjective 'ubiquitous'.

Comment: The ubiquitous you was what I learned to term this usage. I thought it a bit odd at the time, but I did learn the word _ubiquitous_ as a bonus.

Comment: You need to supply another example showing that this is a fixed phrase / compound (like 'hot dog') and not just a free association (like 'wet dog'). But I strongly doubt you'll find one.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: just google "the ubiquitous you" and disregard all references to a pop song. It may not be that current a term, but it gets the point across.

Comment: There are a few examples that could be argued to use the term this way, but not from really credible sources. And usually the hit is for << ubiquitous 'you' >> not << 'ubiquitous you' >>, showing the non-cohesiveness of the string. A few hits, possibly systematic errors; I don't know how many false positives are contained in the 180 000 (including some scholarly articles, eg [this from the Smithsonian](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/when-you-is-really-about-me-180962686/))  for "generic you". But no pop songs, and no complications with the sense "the widespread [word]  'you' ".

Comment: That book is saying that 'you' should be used to address a specific person, the reader, rather than anyone. Which is the exact opposite of the meaning requested. I found no other relevant references to 'ubiquitous you'.

Comment: @Lambie: nothing is linked to a source in German, but thank you for such an informed opinion.

Comment: Which link is it?

Comment: The first but I just realized there is some German but not in actual text of the book.  Sorry. I think the author means its use is ubiquitous. I guess the title is a joke.

Comment: Now that I look at that example, I see it's not the best. Try one of the others.

Answer (score 1):

It's called an **indefinite** or **generic** use of *you*.
It's equivalent to the more formal indefinite pronoun *one*:

- *You never know what you'll find there.*
- *One never knows what one will find there.*

or other indefinite NPs, like

- *People never know what they'll find there.*

In all these examples, the subject NPs don't refer to any specific individual,
but rather to anyone who fits the description in the sentence.

In my experience, the use of the indefinite *you* is especially frequent in giving advice,
where the *you* can refer either specifically to the addressee, or to an indefinite person,
or to both, which makes it convenient.

Comment: Now here we go. Just buzzing along. :)

Comment: It's not the only indefinite usage, of course. Pronouns are tricky little things.