# "This is your rear-window heater." Is this a "your" with "typifying generic force" or is it something unique to marketing?

Tags: pronouns, register, marketing

I've just gotten behind the wheel at the car dealership. The sales rep continues talking: "This is *your* rear-window heater and here is *your* electronic parking break." This use of *your* rubs me the wrong way. (The rep may be projecting a sale, but I'm mentally rejecting a purchase. Neither the car nor the heater are mine.)

A bellhop opens my room and gives the tour of the amenities. "This is *your* climate unit, and *your* entertainment center is over there." This feels *marginally* better and more appropriate, because it's something that's temporarily mine to use. The same would hold for an explanation in a rental car that I'll be driving.

The closest I have come to identifying this usage is Quirk et al., *A Comprehensive Grammar* p.283:

> Another determinative word used with typifying generic force is *your*
>
> *Your average football supporter is not interested in comfort.*
>
> In contrast to *the*, this use of *your* is associated with familiar
> speech; but it resembles *the* in its focus on the 'typical specimen'
> of the class.

Is my salesperson's usage just the same (but perhaps *too*) familiar speech? Or is (what I think of as) the "creepy *your*" different, and does it have a name? If so, is it specific to marketing language?

Comment: Probably close enough to be a duplicate of [What is it called ... when I use the word'you' to mean everyone?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/350854/what-is-it-called-or-the-term-for-when-i-use-the-word-you-to-mean-everyone/350855#350855) etc.

Comment: The cases there do seem to be the "everyone" usage, but some instances feel very personal when you  are addressed and included--not so much an *everyone.*

Comment: There are other threads on _generic you_; doubtless one addresses the pragmatic differences between 'one' and 'you'.

Answer (score 6):

> "This is your rear-window heater and here is your electronic parking break."

This is not the generic “your”. You can tell this by the fact that the salesperson will address you as “you”.

In this context, the relative adjective/determiner implies a potential personal control over its noun.

You would be able to see this if they added “… and if you glance upwards, you will see your self-dipping mirror through which you can see your spouse.”

This personalisation is a small psychological device that you will/ are intended to subconsciously translate as

*"And when I buy the car, this is my rear-window heater that I will control, and here, when I buy the car, is my electronic parking break that I will control."*

The problem of which the salesperson was unaware was that you happen to translate “your” as the informal/generic “any example of”, as in

“Now, friend, this is your common-or-garden rear-window heater.” Something that a salesperson is unlikely to intend.

Granted, in some cases it is not easy to discern the difference but the generic "your" is most commonly used of objects over which you have, and are likely to have, little control:

"Now your average camel is a flea-bitten, obstinate bastard that will spit at you as soon as look at you."

and used in very informal contexts, often to convey "interesting facts" or personal, expert, knowledge from the speaker's life experience.

Did you buy the car?

Comment: I think it's more subtle than that - the salesman might be pretending to use the generic *your* while knowing your subconscious will hear the personal *your*.

Comment: It's not very *sub* on my end :-) I have mentioned this on occasion to friends who also don't care for this usage. I'm not saying I take take offense (I don't and the sales rep are usually very nice) -- it's just a bit of the chalk-on-the-blackboard, can't-help-but-notice-you-said-that feeling.

Comment: It's also a common psychological trick to get you thinking of something as already belonging to you, so you will face some sense of loss if you fail to obtain it.

Comment: I have also noticed (and always despised) this particular bit of marketing pop psychology. It is rank manipulation that occurs in many television ads, especially noticeable by the speaker's emphasis on the word *you* or *your*, or the phrase "get all the [whatever they are selling] *you* deserve!" Ick.

Comment: I don't really agree that if someone is addressing you by "you" they cannot freely mix in the generic "you."  If someone says to me "you can't win them all," I'm almost certainly not going to take that as being a claim about me, specifically, even if they call me "you" in the previous or following sentence.

Answer (score 4):

This usage is not specific to marketing language. Instead, it is common to familiar usage. As Collins notes:

> **your** *determiner*
> 3. *informal* used to indicate all things or people of a certain type: *your part-time worker is a problem.*
> <sub>[TFD Online](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/your)</sub>

American Heritage (at same link) adds this note:

> 3. *Informal* Used with little or no sense of possession to indicate a type familiar to the listener: *your basic three-story frame house*.

So it is general and informal, with the nuance of something that is *familiar to the listener* (I would add "to the speaker", since it implies a special knowledge of the subject.)

Note that the above description does describe many marketing communications, but the usage is so general that there is certainly no cornering of the *your* market there.

**Addendum**

As I mentioned in a comment:

> ... the salesman may also be trying to position the vehicle as, somewhat proleptically, *belonging to the prospective buyer*.

Whether this is what you're reacting to I can't say (and that is beyond the scope of this site anyway). But it is certainly common for salespeople to do whatever they can to have you "try on" ownership of the object being sold, although the line between that and simply using *your* as a more familiar-sounding determiner is blurred and possibly not something that can be determined in every case.

Comment: That is why I cited  the "typifying generic force" in the question. However, the feature being pointed out might be brand new, quite obscure, or specific to a certain model, and not at all *familiar* to me nor the general public.

Comment: @DjinTonic It's not that literal. 'your' is certainly familiar here but in register. It has no connotation of something you are familiar with.

Comment: Is there a distinction between the *Oxford American's*: "Your -- Informal - used to denote someone or something that is familiar or typical of its kind: *I'm just your average Joe* and "familiar" in register as in *This is your temperature control*?

Comment: @DjinTonic: It is a blurry line, but it always seems to indicate that the speaker wishes to seem folksy in a familiar way. However, in the case of the temperature control, the salesman may also be trying to position the vehicle as, somewhat proleptically, *belonging to the prospective buyer*.

Comment: @DjinTonic For the purpose of this Question, "your" has exactly the same meaning as "the"

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Yes, the meaning is the same, but as Quirk says "...it resembles *the* in its focus on the 'typical specimen' of the class" So not *exactly* same in how it comes across.

Comment: @DjinTonic How you interpret what you hear is one thing. Please be very sure, in standard native English there is not the slightest difference in meaning; only in regional, or more likely personal, usage.

If you doubt that, why not try asking the same Question in English Language Learners?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin As a native speaker, I have no doubt as to the meaning. That's not what the question is about. I have *register* as a tag.

Comment: @DjinTonic Can you explain why you have register as a tag?

Notwithstanding Quirk et al, it remains true that in standard native English there is not the slightest difference in meaning; only in regional, or more likely personal, usage. If you doubt that, why not try asking the same Question in English Language Learners?

Comment: Love the 'But it is certainly common for salespeople to do whatever they can to have you "try on" ownership of the object being sold. ' When teaching, an educational psychologist strongly recommended "Stop hitting Jenny, John, thank you" rather than "Stop hitting Jenny, John, please" to promote compliance. Get the desired result by conferred ownership.

Comment: *Try on ownership* like telling the woman in the store *Slip into this dress and lets see  how it looks*  or *Slip behind the wheel of this baby!*

Answer (score 3):

This is unique to sales and marketing, but the psychological device is seen elsewhere. It is part of a sales technique called the **presumptive close**.

> The assumptive selling technique, also known as a **presumptive close**, takes place when a salesperson intentionally assumes that *the customer has already said yes to the sale*. For example, an assumptive statement from the salesperson might be "give me your credit card and I'll get the paperwork started."

> The assumptive close works well because it comes across as professional and is used as part of an intentional sales process. To implement it effectively, you must have a clear understanding of the customer's needs and desires beforehand. If you have listened well and matched the customer up with the perfect product or solution for their needs, then there is nothing more to discuss with the customer, except for how they intend to pay for their purchase.

(from https://www.thebalancesmb.com/assuming-the-sale-3887432)

The car salesman is having you envision the car as your own as you are literally in the driver's seat. It is not in fact *your* rear-view mirror or *your* car; however, the salesman wants you to make a psychological shift towards ownership.

Comment: One salesman of home products said the words *presumptive close" while getting out his order pad. A Dodge dealer also used the presumptive close, intensifying my dislike of their products. The salesman was trying to make me feel that I was letting him down by not buying the car.

Comment: Correct, and I said in the question "Neither the car nor the heater are mine."  The technique is transparent for this very reason.  I would point out that the usage can occur very early in the sales pitch, even just after I've arrived -- not even a test drive.  Perhaps it's an opening gambit. (The rep may show me another model; is that "my" car too? The rep hopes so.)

Comment: OK, so you might not literally be in the driver's seat. But isn't the salesman maneuvering for the Jedi mind trick? Instead of "These are not the droids you are looking for," he says, "This is the rear-view mirror you've been looking for.*"

Answer (score 1):

Here is the *OED*’s definition (along with a couple of usage examples) for the *your* that maps to the usage in Quirk:

> **B. *adj.*** The possessive adjective corresponding to *ye*, *you*.
> **1. d.** Used to designate a person or thing known or familiar to the person or people being addressed, or which is typical of its kind.
> Sometimes with derogatory implication. Cf. *your actual* —— at ACTUAL
> *adj.* 2b(b).
>  <sub>. . .</sub>
>  <sub>1978    *Billboard* 30 Sept. 48/4    Take your big stores for an example.</sub>
>  <sub>2010
>   J. STUMP r. P. Siniac *Collaborators* 66    Your Frenchman
> isn’t so prissy, everything cracks him up.</sub>

However, what you are describing matches the *OED*’s definition at:

> **5.** Belonging to or associated with any hearer or reader; one’s. Cf. YOU *pron.* 8.
> <sub>. . .</sub>
>  <sub>1981    *N.Y.
> Mag.* 16 Nov. 177/3    As you walk through the living room, you
> almost have to catch your breath at the view of the lake and distant
> mountains.</sub>
>  <sub>1992    *Hamilton (*Ont.*) Spectator*
> 30 June c1/4    Letting the rope feed through your hands is the
> essence of rap-jumping.</sub>

That is the possessive determiner form of what is known as the [*generic you*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22generic+you%22+grammar).

So, I wouldn’t take it personally.

<sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

Comment: In the 1981 example, when I read it I feel it equivalent to  "As one walks through the living room". Perhaps the difference in feeling hinges on the fact that the "your" is addressed to me. The salesman isn't going to say "This is one's electronic break," but the "your" doesn't feel as neutral as the living room tour.

Comment: Imagine *This here’s your rear-window heater* in parallel to *This here’s your hook, and this here’s your bar* in [this passage](https://www.google.com/books/edition/It_Is_Time_Lord/Uktt5_YQ3yUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22this+here%27s+your%22&pg=PA12&printsec=frontcover) (starting on the page above the yellow highlights).

Comment: Yes, it's definitely parallel, but when an adult is addressing  a younger loved one IMO it has  an intent and a perception that differs from a stranger or acquaintance addressing another adult. Just as the narrative "Imagine yourself walking..." These all could be addressing or including me (in the one case I am still a child), but I feel them all differently and I think it's built into the intent/usage, not just my imagination or perception.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to imagine the same usage in a TV program about cars. So it's not a personal *your*. But it's not the same as *Your average football supporter*, either. It is an *indefinite personal possessive pronoun*.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/you) has this as its sixth definition for *you*:

> (indefinite personal pronoun) Anyone, one; an unspecified individual or group of individuals (as subject or object).

For example, "You can't always get what you want." It's not creepy at all.

If we can imagine Prince Andrew reduced to the rank of car salesman, it might go like this:

> This is one's rear-window heater and here is one's electronic parking brake.

To my ears, this has exactly the same meaning as the OP's example sentence.

Comment: If I say *It's a shame this model doesn't come in that model's metallic blue*  and the rep says *Yes, but unfortunately, you can't always get what you want*, I take it as a saying that applies to my case. *This is the electronic parking brake* and the unlikely *This is one's electronic parking brake* do have the same meaning as *This is your electronic parking brake* but lack the folksy register, which some like me, but clearly not, all find a little off-putting.

Comment: @DjinTonic: I think even in your context _You can't always get what you want_ is the indefinite personal pronoun. Otherwise it would be intrusive to my ears, if not bossy. Having said that, it seems that we are in broad agreement here.

Comment: I agree completely. I meant to distinguish it from the "off-putting" case.

Answer (score 0):

In these contexts, *your* is most definitely not a vehicle of 'typifying generic force'. In fact, it is the opposite of that: the salesperson is trying to create in your mind an illusion that there is some sort of a special bond between you and the object that is offered for sale.

As has already been pointed out in more than one answer, one psychological mechanism of creating that bond would be to get you to think of the car as if you already owned it. By using *your* the salesperson may be trying to accomplish that, and thus weaken your resistance to buying the car. It is possible, however, that another mechanism is at work.

Consider ordering a hamburger in a restaurant. The waiter might ask 'How would you like your hamburger?' or 'What would you like on your hamburger?'. As you are waiting, the waiter may reassure you 'Your hamburger will be ready in a minute'. In bringing a bottle of ketchup to the table, the waiter may say 'Here is some ketchup for your hamburger'. In these cases, the use of *your* is entirely unproblematic, as there is a straightforward sense in which the hamburger is yours, even though it is not yet in front of you. Nevertheless, it should be noted that *your* is usually not necessary in these locutions, as it is obvious from the context which hamburger is referred to; *the* would have been sufficient. By using *your*, instead of *the*, the waiter brings to your attention, that the hamburger is being made specially for you, that care is being taken to ensure that it precisely satisfies your wishes.

The car salesperson's use of *your* may be an extension of the waiter's. Although the car is, obviously, not really built specially for you, the salesperson may be trying to create the impression that the designers anticipated your wishes, and have made the car in accordance with these wishes, as if they were making it specially for you. They knew, the salesperson would like you to think, that you have always wanted a rear-window heater that works in just this way, and, lo and behold, they have built the car with precisely such a rear-window heater. By referring to the features of the car as yours, the salesperson may be suggesting that they satisfy your wishes.

It is, however, unlikely that these intentions, or any that are articulated in other answers in this page, are consciously present in the mind of every particular salesperson who speaks that way. Many of them unthinkingly pick up that way of speaking from other salespersons, who picked it up from other salespersons, and so forth. Any answer to this question that may be given here, is thus bound to be a somewhat speculative attempt at a reconstruction of what may have been on the minds of whoever started the practice.